# Meteor REST API access

Tags: rest, meteor, meteor-restivus

I am trying to add a REST API to my Meteor application using [Restivus](https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus)

I putted the following code in server folder of my Meteor application. Currently, I am trying to get the URL parameters.

```
      var Api = new Restivus({
        useDefaultAuth: true,
        prettyJson: true
      });

    Api.addRoute('login/:id/:password', {authRequired: true}, {
    get:{
    action: function(){
      var id = this.queryParams.id;
      var password = this.queryParams.password;
          return {
          id: id,
          password: password
          }
      }
    }
  });
```

I got this response

```
{
"status": "error"
"message": "API endpoint does not exist"
}
```

to my request:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/login?id=BGrZbGtKZZQYr9jDR&password=myPassword
```

Comment: Because query parameters are different things than parameters, try `http://localhost:3000/api/login/BGrZbGtKZZQYr9jDR/myPassword`

Answer (score 4):

the way you wrote the url `login/:id/:password` means it is expecting the url to be
`http://localhost:3000/api/login/BGrZbGtKZZQYr9jDR/myPassword`

However in your code, you are looking at the `queryParams` not `urlParams`:

```
var id = this.queryParams.id;
var password = this.queryParams.password;
```

You should choose one or the other:

use the code:

```
var id = this.urlParams.id;
var password = this.urlParams.password;
```

with the `/login/:id/:password` URL,

or use the route with just `/login` and pass the params as query params to use as you described:

`http://localhost:3000/api/login?id=BGrZbGtKZZQYr9jDR&password=myPassword`

```
var Api = new Restivus({
        useDefaultAuth: true,
        prettyJson: true
      });

    Api.addRoute('login', {authRequired: true}, {
    get:{
    action: function(){
      var id = this.queryParams.id;
      var password = this.queryParams.password;
          return {
          id: id,
          password: password
          }
      }
    }
  });
```